# MariaDB Slow Query on Plesk vs local PC

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, plesk

I have the below query, which I appreciate probably isn't well written, but on my local PC with Xampp and MariaDB it executes in 0.1719 seconds, which is about the speed I would hope for.

However, on my development server with Plesk and MariaDB the same query with the same data takes over 12 seconds. Obviously would be no use.

Probably the query could be modified to make it better, but can somebody explain why the performance difference? The server is a VPS, it has no shortage of resources - it isn't live so usage is almost none at all, yet still 12+ seconds for this query.

The query:

```
SELECT  m.id AS match_id, e.event AS event1
    FROM  matches m
    JOIN  competitions co  ON co.id = m.competition
    JOIN  clubs h  ON h.id = m.hometeam
    JOIN  clubs a  ON a.id = m.awayteam
    LEFT JOIN  match_events e  ON e.match = m.id
      AND  e.player = '7138'
    WHERE  (m.hometeam = '1'
              OR  m.awayteam = '1'
           )
      AND  m.season = '121'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need `AND  e.player = '7138'` in the `ON` clause of a `LEFT JOIN` and not in the `WHERE` clause?

**Better indexing**

Recommend these composite, covering, indexes:

```
m:  (season, awayteam, hometeam, competition, id)
e:  (player, match, event)
```

**Avoiding OR**

`OR` optimizes poorly.  A common trick is to turn it into `UNION`.  Such may work for your query:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM matches JOIN ...
    WHERE m.season = 121
      AND m.hometeam = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
    FROM matches JOIN ...
    WHERE m.season = 121
      AND m.awayteam = 1
```

And have these two indexes:

```
INDEX(season, hometeam)  -- will be used by one part of the UNION
INDEX(season, awayteam)  -- will be used by the other
```

I chose `UNION ALL` because it is faster than `UNION DISTINCT`.  But if you get unwanted dups, change it.